# How to write a IPV6 loopback address in array form

Tags: ipv6

The IPV4 address has been written as { 127, 0, 0, 1 }
How to write the loopback address in IPV6 in this format. Do I need to take a 16 sized array???
Isnt there any better way ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, IPv6 has many "shortened" forms, so that a loopback address can be written as `::1` - however, in an array, you'd need to spell out the entire thing (16 * 8 = 128 bits):

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }
```

Comment: @ Piskvor...thanks...this is fine but is there any function that can convert IPV4 address to IPV6 address.Actually in this part of code    memcpy( &addr.sin6_addr, address, (int)sizeof( *address ) ); I want to fill addr.sin6_addr with address which is IPV6 loopback address

Comment: "convert IPV4 address to IPV6"...hmm, well, there's [SIIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanisms#Stateless_IP.2FICMP_Translation_.28SIIT.29), but generally, there isn't a predictable mapping between IPv4 and IPv6 addresses - having one doesn't guarantee having the other (in most of my cases, the IPv6 address is completely unrelated to the IPv4 address of the same network interface).